# How to comment lines matching a pattern in all files of a folder

Tags: text-processing

In one folder I have many files. I want to comment each line if specific pattern exists

Example pattern:

```
`include "xyz.vh"
```

Expected output:

```
// `include "xyz.vh"
```

So please give me guidance for the same.

Answer (score 4):

This might help you,

```
sed '/`include "xyz.vh"/s/^/\/\/ /' filename
```

If you want to search for pattern in all files then you can use this command,

```
find . -type f -exec sed '/`include "xyz.vh"/s/^/\/\/ /' {} \;
```

One more way, using `perl`,

```
perl -p0e 's/(.*`include "xyz.vh"\n)/\/\/ \1/g' file
```

Comment: Use this with `find . -type f -exec . . . .\;`  or even `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed . . . `

Answer (score 2):

Use `grep` to filter files containing the desired pattern

```
grep -rlZ 'pattern'
```

- `-r` option to recursively search directory (by default current directory) including sub-directories
- `-l` list only filenames matching the pattern
- `-Z` output separated by zero byte (to handle file  names  containing  unusual characters like  newlines) that can then be passed onto program like `sed` or `perl` using `xargs -0` to perform the search and replace

Putting it all together:

```
grep -rlZ '`include "xyz.vh"' | xargs -0 perl -i -pe 's|^|// | if /`include "xyz.vh"/'
```

- `-i` option will modify the input file itself with changes

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '/`include "xyz.vh"/ {print "// " $0; next} 1' file.txt
```

To edit the file in place, using recent GNU `awk`:

```
awk -i inplace '/`include "xyz.vh"/ {print "// " $0; next} 1' file.txt
```

For all other `awk` implementations, use a temporary file:

```
awk '/`include "xyz.vh"/ {print "// " $0; next} 1' file.txt >file.txt.tmp && \
    mv file.txt.tmp file.txt
```

For all files starting from current directory, recursively:

```
find . -type f -exec awk -i inplace '/`include "xyz.vh"/{print "// " $0; next} 1' {} \;

find . -type f -exec sh -c 'awk "/`include "xyz.vh"/ {print "// " $0; next} 1" "$1" \
       >"$1".tmp && mv "$1".tmp "$1"' _ {} \;
```